# How to make buttons and labels appear and disappear

Tags: ios, swift, button, sprite-kit, label

### What I want to know:

I want to know that how to make buttons/labels appear and disappear. When my character collides with an object the buttons/labels will show up over the view and the game-view wont be working any more, only the buttons/labels that appeared can be interacted with.

### What I have tried:

I have tried `.hidden = false` and `.hidden = true` but it didn't work but maybe I was not using it correctly.

### CODE: I have delete unnecessary code!

```
import Foundation

import AVFoundation

import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var movingGround: PPMovingGround!
var square1: PPSquare1!
var square2: PPSquare2!
var wallGen: PPWallGen!

var isStarted = false
var isGameOver = false


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


    addMovingGround()
    addSquare1()
    addWallGen()
    start()


}

func addSquare1() {
    square1 = PPSquare1()
    square1.position = CGPointMake(70, movingGround.position.y + movingGround.frame.size.height/2 + square1.frame.size.height/2)
    square1.zPosition = 1
    playerNode.addChild(square1)
}

func addWallGen() {
    wallGen = PPWallGen(color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: view!.frame.size)
    wallGen.position = view!.center
    addChild(wallGen)
}


func start() {
    isStarted = true

    //square2.stop()
    square1.stop()
    movingGround.start()
    wallGen.startGenWallsEvery(1)
}


// MARK - Game Lifecycle


func gameOver() {
    isGameOver = true

    // everything stops

    //square2.fall()
    square1.fall()
    wallGen.stopWalls()
    diamondGen.stopDiamonds()
    movingGround.stop()
    square1.stop()
    //square2.stop()


    // create game over label
    let gameOverLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "Game Over!")
    gameOverLabel.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    gameOverLabel.fontName = "Helvetica"
    gameOverLabel.position.x = view!.center.x
    gameOverLabel.position.y = view!.center.y + 80
    gameOverLabel.fontSize = 22.0
    addChild(gameOverLabel)

func restart() {

    let newScence = GameScene(size: view!.bounds.size)
    newScence.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    view!.presentScene(newScence)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    if isGameOver {
        restart()
    } else {
        square1.flip()
    }

}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {


// MARK: - SKPhysicsContactDelegate
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {


    if !isGameOver {
        gameOver()
    } else {
        println("error, not game over!"        
}
```

Comment: So you mean the buttons weren't disappearing and reappearing when you set `.hidden` to `false/true`?

Comment: @Kametrixom yes, but I must of not used the command correctly can you show me an example. As my buttons/labels are always appearing in my game so...idk. I put my button in the Main.storyboard so then it overlaps the game when it's playing. But I don,t want that I want it just to appear when the player collides with something. Which I have already set up something for that I just need to know how to work with the commands.

Comment: Then you have to set the "hidden" property in the attribute inspector on the right to false, then it won't show in the beginning

Comment: @Kametrixom ok that hid them, but now how do I make them appear when it collides with my object?

Comment: Just set the `hidden` property to true. I don't have any experience with collisions in SpriteKit, so I cannot help you there, but I'm sure you'll find lots of tutorials if you just search it in Google

Comment: @Kametrixom I have but they are all in objective-c :(

Comment: It's not that hard to infer the Swift from Objective-C, just try it ;)

Comment: Duude just search for "Swift SpriteKit Collision". Google isn't THAT hard, there are dozens of tutorials

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your code, this is a little hard to determine, but I would suggest the following:

1. Be sure you have connected the buttons to an Outlet variable. This is critical. Without connecting them, you can use the hidden boolean, but it would not have an effect on an actual button.
2. Be sure you are not somehow undoing your own changes. For example, further down in the code, you might have something which is setting hidden to false even after you set it to true, and so on.
3. In some cases, you might want to set your outlet variable as strong instead of weak. This may retain changes that are being lost with a view switch.
4. You can also use "alpha" such as:

   myButton.alpha = 0

as an alternate way of controlling visibility. 0 would set the alpha to none (which would make the button invisible) and 1 would set the alpha to full (which would make the button visible again.)

5. Right after you set hidden (or alpha) put in:
   println("i hid the button!")
   just to be sure the code you think you are executing really is being executed. Sometimes code we think is not working is actually not even being called.

Please provide more info and I will gladly work to get this solved for you.